# Wait for thunk to finish the HTTP request before checking state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, redux-thunk

I'm kinda new and learning phase of React-Redux using thunk, so I have this `login` state which have `isLoggedIn` boolean against which I want to check if I want user to redirect to the home screen.

So, I'm making a thunk request to my `Node.JS` server which returns the user and I set the `isLoggedIn` flag to `true`, but when I validate it against it, I need to click the `Login` button twice to redirect.

I'm 99% sure that it's because of the async thunk behavior, my question is how to solve it?

```
const Login = ({ authenticate, IsUserLoggedIn }) => {
        const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
        const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
        const history = useHistory()
    
        const onSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const user = {
                email,
                password
            }
            authenticate(user); //<---- Thunk Request
            if (IsUserLoggedIn) {      //<---- Initially false, set to true on successful login
                history.push('/tracker')
            }
        }
        return (
            <>
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-control">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter email..." />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-control">
                        <label htmlFor="Password">Password </label>
                        <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter password..." />
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn">Login</button>
                </form>
            </>
        )
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        IsUserLoggedIn: getIsUserLoggedIn(state)
    })
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        authenticate: user => dispatch(getUser(user))
    })
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

This is my `Thunk` request

```
export const getUser = user => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        let body = JSON.stringify(user)
        const response = await axios.post('/api/v1/users/login',body, config)
        dispatch(setUserInfo(response))
    }
    catch (error) {
       dispatch(userError(error.response.data.error))
    }
}
```

This seems like a really general question, but can't seem to find the solution. Let me know if any more code is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
const Login = ({ authenticate, IsUserLoggedIn }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (IsUserLoggedIn) {
      history.push('/tracker');
    }
  }, [IsUserLoggedIn, history]);
```

Not sure if useHistory returns the same object every time but I would think so.